# Prove that the product of $2n$ consecutive negative integers is divisible by $(2n)!$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-proofs

### My approach

Let $x$ be a sufficiently large number such that the product of numbers from $x$ to $x-(2n-1)$ is $P$

$$P=x(x-1)(x-2) \ldots (x-(2n-1))$$
$$P(x-2n)!= x!$$
$$P=\frac{x!}{(x-2n)!}$$

Now, we have to prove that $(2n)!$ divides $P$.

### Cannot continue...

I can't take it from here. I tried proving by expanding it but failed. Any other approach to the problem is welcome.

Comment: Thank You and yes, this answers my question

Comment: If something is an answer to a counting problem, it must be an integer.